# htaccess rule question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a htaccess which looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ /naujausios [L,R]
```

And I'm not sure where to put this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

for it to work properly - I tried a few modifications to the keys at the end, without success - I just end up with a 500 response. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please tell us what are you trying to do and you also need to tell your original and target URL.

Comment: the code that I've posted is universal, so you shouldn't need the URL. I'm trying to redirect the site to a non-www address whenever the www address is entered.

Comment: What you have should work...have you tried hardcoding the RewriteRule domain, `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://somedomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`?  Also, have you tried the non-www rewrite with your original rewrite commented out, to make sure there is not a conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had conflicts wherever I put it, but the solution was to put the www bit rewrite at the very top just after RewriteEngine on